# Por quê recebo este erro no locale.h? [Error] expected declaration specifiers or '...' before numeric constant

Tags: c, biblioteca, declaração-de-variável, include, locale

O erro ( [Error] expected declaration specifiers or '...' before numeric constant ) é apontado no

setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

Porém, a biblioteca locale.h e a vírgula estão presentes e declaradas no código anteriormente, por que recebo este erro?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

#ifndef _BIBLIO_H
#define _BIBLIO_H

#include "biblio.h"

#define lim 100
#define prod 500


setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

//declarando as funções do programa
void cadastro();
int cad_fornecedor();
int cad_produto();
void menu();
```

Comment: O setlocale deve estar dentro de uma função, provavelmente a main.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como o @anonimo citou, `setlocale()` precisa estar dentro da `main()`, ou de alguma outra função, e especulo que um dos fatores abaixo estejam relacionados a esse erro.

- O `setlocale(LC_ALL, "C");` ser executado antes de qualquer outro código do usuário.
- E o comportamento ser indefinido quando o `setlocale()` é chamado de alguma thread, enquanto outra thread está executando um `printf()` ou até o próprio `setlocale()` por exemplo.